# ¿Cómo solucionar el error "Conjunto de caracteres inicial: latin1 Conjunto de caracteres actual: utf8"?

Tags: php, html, mysql

¿Cómo solucionar el error

> "Conjunto de caracteres inicial: latin1 Conjunto de caracteres actual:
>   utf8"

?

Añado el código:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
require('session_start.php');
$idUsuario=$_SESSION['idUsuario'];
$modalidadPreguntas=$_SESSION['modalidadPreguntas'];

$consulta="SELECT respuestasCorrectas FROM respuestasTestUsuario WHERE idUsuario = '$idUsuario' AND modalidadPreguntas = '$modalidadPreguntas' ORDER BY numeroPregunta";

echo "<div style='width:100%;'>";
$contador=0;
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$consulta))
{
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $contador++;
    //echo $row[0]."<br>";
        if($row[0]==0){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";

        }
        if($row[0]==1){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.2); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==2){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.4); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==3){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.6); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==4){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 1); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";

        }
    }
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

BASE DE DATOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código te está regresando ese error que mencionas? ¿Al imprimir la variable `$contador`?

Comment: el problema lo tenía en el archivo de conexion.php ahí tenía un par de print. ¡Gracias! ; )

Comment: Si ya lo solucionaste, publica tu respuesta para ayudar a la comunidad.

Comment: @r84 la solución no va en la pregunta, para eso tienes abajo la zona de respuestas

Comment: @r84 revertí tu edición además el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Tenía en el archvo de conexión: printf("Conjunto de caracteres inicial: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($con)); y printf("Conjunto de caracteres actual: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($con)); De manera que al añadir "//" se solucionó.